# Django Admin - How to embed View from Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a simple relationship with a `Question` that contains a `Label`.

```
class Label(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subtext = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.OneToOneField(Label, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

If I open up the admin panel to edit a `Label`, it shows 2 text fields to update the `text` and `subtext`. However, if I attempt to edit the `Question`, it'll be a dropdown list of all `Labels`.

What is the best way to make it straightforward to edit the `Question` and it's child `Label`?

In the example above, I would want all 3 text fields ( `text`, `subtext` and `question` ) in the same view and editing them will update the correct tables in the database.

Comment: Why not have the fields on the `Question` model? The admin adds some icons next to the dropdown for creating and editing related models

Comment: @IainShelvington The example I gave was just the most simple example for this problem, in my actual project I'm using the `Label` Model in a lot more places. Although I was looking into Embedding the `Label` model into the `Question` model, but that sounds only possible with MongoDB.

Comment: Updating a Question and having the result of that affect other questions seems like bad design?

Comment: It's a 1:1 relationship, the `Label` is only used for this specific `Question`.

Comment: If it's a 1:1 relationship why not use a `models.OneToOneFIeld`?

Comment: I didn't know that existed! That may be a way easier solution. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: A `OneToOneFIeld` is usually used when a model is in a related app and you want to add some extra fields to it. Just add the fields to your model and get rid of the relationship

Comment: I can't add the fields to the Model as the actual project structure is fairly nested, where the `Question` could contain any number of `Labels`, and each `Label` contains multiple fields. It's a bit hard to explain while still making the problem easy to understand. I tried changing it to a `OneToOneField`, but the admin panel still shows the same dropdown list.

Comment: "the Question could contain any number of Labels" - how? Wether you use a `ForeignKey` or a `OneToOneField` each `Question` only has one label

Comment: In my actual project, `Object A` contains an Array of `Object B` which contains 2 `Object C` which each contain 2 `Object D`. I want to figure out a way to allow the user to edit the `Object D`  while looking at `Object A`.

Comment: Maybe an inline would be more appropriate?

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for, but it's close. Because `Object C` has 2 Foreign Keys to 2 `Object D`s, I put the inline on `Object C`. But the result was I could edit `Object C` while looking at `Object D` - backwards of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a conversation with someone who was more familiar with database design and he suggested inverting the structure as "all subordinate children should have references to their parents". If you read the tutorials for Django, they use the poll example which has a `Question` and `Choices`, and each `Choice` has a reference to a `Question`.

So I changed up my models to be more this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def title(self):
        labels = self.get_labels()
        return labels[0].text

class Label(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subtext = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And then using inlines to allow the view to be editable.